# PDF editing in PHP

Tags: php, zend-framework, pdf, edit, fpdf

I have some module in PHP.
With this module I have to substitute in PHP some string with another string that i extract from DB.
I have to do a merge : I have to find the fixed label on the module and substitute it with the value of the db.
Can anyone help me in order to do this kind of manipulation of pdf?
The manipulated pdf has to be show on the monitor and then printed. Finally it can be saved by name.

Answer (score 0):

I'am not sure I understand your question. Are you asking on how to generate a PDF doc of your data from DB??

Comment: No, if my pdf contais a marker [DATA] i've to search&find it into the pdf and substitute it with the DATA fields on the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clearly how exactly you're going about this. Are you saying your PDF is already generated and *then* you're wanting to do the search and replace? If there's a way you could do it before generating the PDF it might be easier like maybe saving the label in memory, then query the db and do the search and replace. Then you could use MPDF. http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/

```
// do your search and replace here etc. then,

require_once('mpdf/mpdf.php');
$mpdf=new \mPDF('c');
$mpdf->AddPage();

$mpdf->WriteHTML($your_content);
$mpdf->Output();
```

Comment: Yes my PDF is already generated and then I want to do the search and replace. The PDF is a template and I cannot do S&R before generating the pdf. Can you help me?

Comment: You could try one of these: http://pastebin.com/dvwySU1a OR http://webcheatsheet.com/php/reading_clean_text_from_pdf.php Those should give the you the plain text and allow you to do your search and replace. But, that of course would just be doing the s&r on the plain text so you'd have to regenerate the PDF with the new text.